# Textbox that allows values -9999 to 9999

Tags: javascript, html

Hello this is what I have right now to allow only numbers and a max of 4 digits. How would I make it so that I can allow a - before the number which would bypass the max 4 digit limit? Currently if I use a - only 3 numbers can be entered after, while I need to make it allow 4 numbers.

```js
// Only Numbers can be Entered
function fNumOnly(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

  if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 45) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="text" onkeypress="return fNumOnly(event);" maxlength="4" />
```

Comment: you can try `/^(-)?(\d){0,4}$` regex in pattern
`^` assert the position at start and `$` assert the position at end
`(-)?` is used to match `-` 0 or 1 times
`(\d){0,4}` is used to match digits i.e `0-9` between 0 to 4 times

Comment: @AayushSharma That doesn't limit the input to 4 digits though? I can type as many as I want, and if I use maxlength with that I end up with the same problem i have currently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML text input allows only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allows-only-numeric-input)

Comment: @ShadowZero it should limit the input to 4 digits according to [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BKrSWJ/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check length of value of input using regex.

```js
function fNumOnly(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

  if (
    ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 45) &&
    evt.target.value.match(/^-?\d{0,3}$/g)
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="text" onkeypress="return fNumOnly(event);" />
```

Also you can use `type=number` and `min`&`max` attribute for input instead of checking `charCode` in function

```js
function fNumOnly(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

  if (evt.target.value.match(/^-?\d{0,3}$/g))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="number" onkeypress="return fNumOnly(event);" min="-9999" max="9999"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
I'm trying to figure out the regex stuff and was wondering, would I add something to the end of that regex to prevent additional hyphens?

Comment: @ShadowZero So you should add new condition. http://jsfiddle.net/pdfw52yo/

Answer (score 6):

Why not use `<input type="number">` with min and max values? For example:

```css
input:valid {
  border-color: green;
}

input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Enter a number between -9999 and 9999 (green for valid entry, red for invalid entry)</div>
<input type="number" name="num" min="-9999" max="9999" required>
```

Comment: Point regarding cross browser compatibility: `<input type="number">` compatibility is "unknown" for the Edge browser. I just tested this snippet in Edge and it works fine, but you would have to test the use of this type of element in the context of whatever was being developed to be sure.

Comment: Yeah, bizarrely it looks like this was still an issue [last month](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110895/)

Comment: I actually tried this previously, however I didn't use it because I wanted to fully restrict the input instead of just receiving an error when the input goes beyond the max/min

Comment: In that case, the answer from @Mohammad gets the job done for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to your desired button instead, and then upon firing of that event, run the specified function.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("txtFahrenheit");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (input.value < -9999) {
    input.value = -9999;
  } else if (input.value > 9999) {
    input.value = 9999;
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="number" min="-9999" max="9999">
```

By setting the input type to number, we don't have to have code that checks for the input char. By adding max and min to it, we don't allow a user to use the up and down arrows to reach an invalid range.

The attached code however, double ensures this. If they input anything, it will immediately be reverted to the max and min values.

Without it, someone could manually type in 100000 and it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="text" maxlength="4">
```

Then have the script:

```
const input = document.getElementById("txtFahrenheit");

input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  if(input.value.indexOf("-") != -1) input.maxLength = 5;
  else input.maxLength = 4;
});
```

This will let you type four characters in the input field, unless there is a minus among them, in which case, the max will be five characters.

Comment: Have you tried what happens when someone first add a `-` and then remove it and add a fifth number?

Comment: Excellent point! I need to add an else statement... Edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below:

```html
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="number" oninput="checkLength(this);" />

<script>

function checkLength(inp)
{

if (inp.value > 0)
{
if (inp.value.length > 4)
{
inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, 4);
}
}
else
{
if (inp.value.length > 5)
{
inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, 5);
}

}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Answer w/o an explanation is a bad one. Describe what you did and why it works.

Comment: @LGSon Not required always. This is small and self explanatory

Comment: @LGSon you may try reread again before sharing link, ".....Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful...."  there is no such thing given on indent and as far the script works and run it is All Good!